# How to make foreign key on postgres system catalog tables/views?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

In one of our table we have the following columns:

`id, date, name, timezone(string)`

How can we make sure that timezone can only be one from `pg_timezone_names` table? 
How can we create a foreign key for that ?

Comment: The problem is that "table" is really a view.  And the view is defined by table-valued functions.  Three options:  (1) Use a trigger.  (2) Create your own version of the table to use for foreign key relationships.  (3) Use a user-defined function and a check constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what I would usually recommend, but you can use a `check` constraint that returns an error instead of true or false:

```
 check (timezone( timezone, '2000-01-01'::timestamp) is not null)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf28e704b40dd0a277ce7624f6b4925b) is an example.